# Why does my OS X menu bar randomly take on the background or screen saver colors?

Tags: macos

It seems that my OS X 10.8 menu bar randomly takes on the coloring of the background or screensaver, albeit severely pixelated. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

<sup>([Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjKxc.png))</sup>

Does anyone know how to make this stop?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually [much smoother than that](http://cloud.danielgroves.net/bGZD). I can only imagine you system is low on Graphics memory which would be why it's doing it. You can turn it off in System preferences -> Desktop and Screen Saver. Small checkbox at the bottom called 'Translucent menu bar' (this is in Mountain Lion).